# Accessing keyboard list to switch keyboards

Tags: android

I was wondering how I can access the keyboard list that you normally access by going to...

settings>language and keyboard>Input methods

I want that "list" of keyboards to pop up and the user to be able to select it, all within my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to show the Input Method picker:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Also, you may want to know whether it is necessary to show the dialog. You can do that like this:

```
private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "com.yourpackage.keyboard.LatinIME";
private static final String IME_NAME = "com.yourpackage.keyboard/.LatinIME";

private boolean isMyKeyboardEnabled(){
    List<InputMethodInfo> inputMethods = mImeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    for(InputMethodInfo inputMethodInfo : inputMethods){
        if( SERVICE_NAME.equals(inputMethodInfo.getServiceName()) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isYourKeyboardSelected(){
    return IME_NAME.equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD));
}
```

In this case LatinIME is the name of the class that extends `InputMethodService`.